# Invalid reference format

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I'm getting an "invalid reference format" error when trying to run a docker container on Windows using the below syntax, following the below guide.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/

ERROR
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

docker container run --name jenkins-docker --rm --detach ^

--privileged --network jenkins --network-alias docker ^

--env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs ^

--volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client ^

--volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home ^

--volume "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%":/home ^

docker:dind

I've also tried running it as one big long command (below) and get the same error?

docker container run --name jenkins-docker --rm --detach --privileged --network jenkins --network-alias docker --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home --volume "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%":/home docker:dind

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance :-)

Greg

Comment: What docker version you have? Did you succeed with volume creation? What you get when you list volumes:

```docker volume ls```

Comment: Check that all your spaces are really spaces and dashes are really dashes. If you copied them from somewhere instead of typing them, type them explicitly.

Comment: Hey GintsGints, Docker version is 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838. And yes, volumes created fine, as did the bridge network creation...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. also when I copied from the tutorial. you need to remove the characters "^" and try to enter in one line. also check for the presence of all "--"

Comment: please explain WHY this helps. also, is the final horizontal line character a hyphen or an em-dash or some other character that looks like a  hyphen?